# Pass id of label in javascript function passed in textbox event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to pass client id of label as parameter in javascript function. I want to show hide label based on if there is value in textbox then show label else hide label.

Please find my code

```
  <label>
    First Name:<asp:Label ID="lblfname" Text="*" CssClass="red-txt" runat="server"></asp:Label>
   </label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" MaxLength="100"  CssClass="form-control" onkeyup="javascript:addremovestyle('#<%=lblfname.ClientID%>',this);">
   </asp:TextBox>
```

My javascript function

```
        function addremovestyle(lblid,cntlid) {
            var txt = $(cntlid).val();
            if (!txt) {
                $(lblid).show();
            }
            else {
                $(lblid).hide();
            }

        }
```

Using my above code I am only getting Textbox value, I am not able to find label control, I want to pass label id as parameter since I have to use this function at many places. Please help.

Comment: Can you remind us what the HTML output of `<asp:Label` is please?

Comment: Recommend you give your `<label>` a `for=` to match the input, then find it based on that then find the child `<asp:Label` (a `<span>`?).  This will also allow you to click on the (real) `<label>` to enter the input, which provides improved UX.  `<label for="txtFirstName">First Name...` then `$("[for=" + $(cntlid)[0].id + "] > span")`   (cntlid clearly isn't just the "id" otherwise `$(cntlid)` wouldn't work)

Comment: HTML output of Label is span

Comment: Also, slightly contradicting question:  Title/first line "I want to pass id of label" - Text: "I **don't** want to pass label id".  Can you update the title/question to be clear (looks like you don't want to pass the label id and find it dynamically)

Comment: @freedomn-m corrected

Comment: Ok, if you *do* want to pass the ID, then you'll need to know the ID up-front - there's nothing anyone can do to help you with that.  **But looks like an XY problem**: "I can't find the label, so want to pass its ID" - better to find the label with some simple navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the related label id if your html is always in the same format (`<label><span></label><input/>`) as you can navigate to the span using

```
$("#" + cntlid).prev().find("span")
```

If the input's label (and `<asp:Label`) are not next to each other then there are other ways to find them, eg using `for=`.

Example snippet

```js
function addremovestyle(cntlid) {
  var txt = $("#" + cntlid).val();
  $("#" + cntlid).prev().find("span").toggle(txt === "")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    First Name: <span id="lblfname">*</span>
</label>
<input type='text' id='txtFirstName' onkeyup='addremovestyle("txtFirstName")' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use inside the function call:

```
$(this).closest('label').find('.red-txt').text()
```

to get the label text.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addremovestyle(lblid, cntlid) {
        var txt = $(cntlid).val();
        if (!txt) { lblid.css("visibility", "hidden"); }
        else {    lblid.css("visibility", "visible");  }
    }
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" MaxLength="100"  CssClass="form-control" onkeyup="addremovestyle($('#lblfname'),this);" ClientIDMode="Static"> </asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Label ID="lblfname" Text="First Name:*" CssClass="red-txt" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:Label>
```